# Printing saved HTML to jsp keeps getting corrupted

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a JAVA object where I save a HTML string value I call message.  The saved data looks like the below,

```
You have received a new <a href='' onclick='return popupRentalView('5282053859835904');'>Rental Request 5282053859835904</a>.  Please view your open orders.
```

But when printed to the JSP file and displayed at runtime using

```
<%=pm.getMessage()%>
```

or

```
<%out.print(pm.getMessage());%>
```

The actual html code comes out all messed up,

```
You have received a new <a 5282053859835904');'="" onclick="return popupRentalView(" href="">Rental Request 5282053859835904</a>
```

. Please view your open orders.

Any thoughts on why the displayed string does not match the saved string?

JAVA code for saving is

```
note.setMessage("You have received a new <a href=\"\" onclick='return popupRentalView('"
            + requestId
            + "');'> Rental Request "
            + requestId
            + "</a>.  Please view your open orders.");
```

Comment: copy and paste the relevant parts to a working JSP and Java file, so that the problem is reproduced.  Then post all of both of those.  I give you a 66% chance of finding the problem while you do that; if you don't, then we'll have something we can work with.  This isn't really enough information.

Comment: This also displays the same messed up HTML `<c:out value="${showMessage.message}" escapeXml="false" />`

Comment: Well if you set the escape XML to true, it prints fine but then its not considered part of the HTML

`<tr>
<td>
Message:
<br>
You have received a new <a href='' onclick='return popupRentalView('5282053859835904');'>Rental Request 5282053859835904</a>. Please view your open orders.
</td>
</tr>`

Comment: Note that your desired output is not going to work as the quotes for your onclick attribute aren't nested properly.

Comment: @Musa could you elaborate with the error your refering to please.
What I get

`<a 5950556929523712');'="" onclick="return popupRentalView("> Rental Request 5950556929523712</a>`


What I saved,

`<a onclick='return popupRentalView('5950556929523712');'> Rental Request 5950556929523712</a>.`

Comment: `<a href='' onclick='return popupRentalView('5282053859835904');'>Rental Request 5282053859835904</a>` will render as `<a href="" onclick="return popupRentalView(" 5282053859835904');'="">Rental Request 5282053859835904</a>`. It should be `<a href='' onclick='return popupRentalView("5282053859835904");'>Rental Request 5282053859835904</a>`

Answer (score 0):

@Musa thanks yea I found what you were referring to, fix was

JAVA Code to save

`note.setMessage("You have received a new <a href=\"\" onclick=\"return popupRentalView('"
                + requestId
                + "');\"> Rental Request "
                + requestId
                + "</a>.  Please view your open orders.");`

Then to display it I could use,

`<%=pm.getMessage()%> or <c:out value="${showMessage.message}" escapeXml="false" />`